# I want to play many videos back to back without delay using mpmovieplayer in ios

Tags: ios4, mpmovieplayer

I want to play many videos back to back without delay.movies are in mp4 format and i want to run them from main bundle

Answer (score 1):

[HTTP Live Streaming](https://developer.apple.com/streaming/) supports discontinuity, which allows different video sources to be played with no 'hiccup'.  Of course that is for a server talking with a client.

Perhaps you could generate a .m3u8 index file with all of your videos, and play them locally.  The MPMoviePlayer takes in a .m3u8 file and does everything else for you.  May be worth looking into.